# Make DotNetNuke Multilingual

Tags: multilingual

I have a site with DotNetNuke and I want to create content available in different languages. I was checking the DNN options and I can choose a language, but it doesn't change my content. Not even the "login" button has changed.

Is there a way to make a multilingual site with DotNetNuke?

Comment: Have you installed the language packs?  The content you add clearly WILL NOT be translated.  The only thing that wil be translated is the interface.  More information is required to help you.

Comment: languaje pack of spanish is done. Now i need something that translates or help me to translate the content. Is there a way to detect current languaje of the user visiting the site?

Answer (score 2):

After you installed the Language Pack, you can choose between

- enabling Content Localization in DNN
- using multi-language aware modules such as Nuntio Content

Content Localization creates a copy of every (new and existing) page for every enabled language.

Since I was struggling to achieve a multi-language setup of DNN myself, I wrote about the options and the configuration process [on my blog](http://devio.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/content-localization-in-multi-language-dotnetnuke-6/).